# Check if Handlebars helper already exists?

Tags: handlebars.js

Is there a way in Handlebars to check if the helper that we are trying to register already exists?

I have a case where iam dynamically registering a helper and so dont want to register again if its already there..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't an official documented way to find out if a helper has been registered. However, the helpers are stored in a simple lookup table in `Handlebars.helpers` so you could do this:

```
if(!('helper' in Handlebars.helpers))
    Handlebars.registerHelper('helper', function() { ... });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/QM7QD/1/

You'd probably want to add a check for `Handlebars.helpers` to your test suite, upgrade checklist, or whatever as `Handlebars.helpers` isn't guaranteed to be there.

As an aside, I don't think re-registering a helper is going to be a problem. The new helper will overwrite the old one so it won't matter if both helpers are the same thing; of course if you have several different helpers with the same name then you have bigger problems than double registering a helper.

Comment: Just for the purpose of saving the time to register a helper again; i think its a good thing to have.

Comment: @mivaas19: You might want to take a peek inside `registerHelper` to see if it does anything more than `Handlebars.helpers[name] = fn`, checking first might not save any time.